# can't add maven dependency - apache poi

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, apache-poi

I created this maven project in Eclipse on my mac. The following two artifacts are in my pom. No problem on MAC.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

However when I recently moved the code to Eclipse on my PC I got this weird error "Missing artifact org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.14". And it points to both the dependency block and the first line of pom (see screenshot) [image]. Updated project many times and it did not help.

I have set up two repositories, one public and one institutional.

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>repo</name>
        <url>http://risdevtool01p.mdanderson.edu:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

When I do "mvn clean install -U", it looks like it is trying to download poi and poi-ooxml from two different repositories.

```
Downloading:http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.14/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/poi/poi/3.14/poi-3.14.jar
Downloading: http://risdevtool01p.mdanderson.edu:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/poi/poi/3.14/poi-3.14.jar
Downloading: http://risdevtool01p.mdanderson.edu:8081/artifactory/repo/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.14/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar
```

Comment: Is your eclipse plugin pointing to your .m2 directory?

Comment: what about 'mvn clean install' from a command line?

Comment: @Lee How do I know if eclipse plugin is pointing to my .m2 directory or not? I did install maven after eclipse.

Comment: @ivanenok I ran that in command line and got the following error "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project RIStore_Flow: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.mda.rists:RIStore_Flow:jar:0.0.4: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.14, org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.14: Failure to find org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.14 in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of JBoss repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]"

Comment: what about mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Comment: @ddd ok, try "mvn clean install -U" it's looks like a typical maven problem related to caching info about artifacts

Comment: try also to drop your local repository

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Got this error "An error occurred during dependency resolution.
    Failed to retrieve org.apache.poi:poi-3.14
Caused by: Failure to find org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.14 in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of JBoss repository has elapsed or updates are forced"

Comment: @ivanenok See my edits. It is trying to download poi and poi-ooxml from both repositories and that's when error occurs

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I can't drop local repository since one of the dependencies is from there

Comment: You always can drop your local repo, you will simply need to launch mvn clean install to download again the dependencies

Comment: @ddd looks like Jboss repo is broken. you can add dependency to bintray repo to your pom as described here https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the nexus of `JBoss`, the artifact is not properly deleted indeed we had the version in the list of available versions but the version is not available at the expected location which is http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/poi/poi/3.14/

```
404 - Path /org/apache/poi/poi/3.14/ not found in group repository "Public Repository Group" [id=public].

Path /org/apache/poi/poi/3.14/ not found in group repository "Public Repository Group" [id=public].
```

But, obviously they've just removed this version properly indeed now this version is no more part of the available versions as you can see here http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/poi/poi/ such that if you remove it from your local repository and try again with a command of type `mvn clean install`, it will work

Comment: I dropped my local repository and it works, but I don't understand why removing local repository would help when some artifacts are not available in the public repository(jboss).

Comment: because the repository of JBoss was corrupted, the version of poi was not properly deleted when you tested, now it has been properly removed so by cleaning your local repo, you get everything working properly with no more corrupted artifacts